# Widget alignment in cell pyqt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm developing some tool in PyQT4 and Python 2.7 and I stuck in a little problem. I've 3 buttons in stored in widget and that widget is in cell in the table (QTableWidget). So my problem is that I can't align widget to top of cell and tool doesn't resize row height to defined in widget minimum/fixed height.

Here is how it looks now with method resizeRowToContents.

[image: what I have]

And I want something like this

[image: what I want]

I did something similar with fixed row height but its not the way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem in quite simply way. 
First of all I changed margin of layout to 0px (later I changed that to 3px to have padding) and this made my alignment exactly to top, left corner. Next step was set minimum size for each row and that I made by following line:

```
self.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(30)
```

added in constructor.

After that I received exactly what I want:

1. widget with some pading from top and bottom
2. not fixed size of rows so multiline text in item is allowed as well