# Aligning a QLineEdit inside QtTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

When I try to insert new rows pressing Enter Key, all looks fine until it exceeds the limit of the window. See example below:

[Disalignment example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAgtA.jpg)

I tried this ([Widget alignment in cell pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461143/widget-alignment-in-cell-pyqt#15466536)), that is almost like my problem, but it not fix it.

The next code performs the error:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 1)


def create_empty_row():
    widget_completer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    widget_completer.returnPressed.connect(
        create_empty_row)
    _rows = table.rowCount()
    table.setRowCount(_rows + 1)
    table.setCellWidget(_rows, 0,
                        widget_completer)

create_empty_row()

table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I also try to fill the QTableWidget programmaticly and everything looks well and the QLineEdit are not misaligned. But I have to insert new rows by demand.

How can I align the QLineEdit inside QTableWidget?

Thanks!!

### EDIT

Solved using [resizeRowToContents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeRowToContents)

Comment: I can confirm the problem using your code example. The behavior to me looks like a bug in Qt. The whole column, except most recent line, gets shifted vertically. I don't think this is related to the question you referenced. Probably you need to file a bug report with the Qt project.

Comment: As @g4s0l1n suggest, setting the height of QTableWidget as multiple of the height of QLineEdit do the trick. Also, investigating a bit more, I found the method [resizeRowToContents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeRowToContents), from the parent class of QTableWidget, QTableView, that also do the trick.

As above comment said, it would be a bug, or as I think, the way that I made the code is not the best way to perform what I want. I will clarify this as soon as I can.

Comment: Great find, reminds me of http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#uniformItemSizes-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't set the correct geometry for the different widgets. So, the problem is the height of the QTableWidget should be ScreenHeight - QLineEdit.height. With this change the QLineEdit geometry it doesn't match with the QTableWidget and should be aligned.

I hope that this help you,

Regards

Comment: I do not accept the answer because I want to investigate a bit more before mark the question as solved, but this answer is very helpful.

Comment: Finally, I solved my problem using [resizeRowToContents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeRowToContents), but thanks for your suggestion!